# Emacs: Insert word at point into replace string query

Tags: emacs

Is there an analogue to inserting the word after point into the isearch query by hitting `C-w` after `C-s` but for the replace string (and replace regexp) queries?

I also enjoy Sacha Chua's modification of `C-x` inserting whole word around point into isearch:

http://sachachua.com/blog/2008/07/emacs-keyboard-shortcuts-for-navigating-code/

This too would be really useful in some cases if it could be used in replace string.

I'd be very thankful for any tips!
Thank you!

Comment: [An alternate answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/636687/99066)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will do it, although it isn't as fancy as <kbd>C-w</kbd> in isearch because you can't keep hitting that key to extend the selection:

```
(defun my-minibuffer-insert-word-at-point ()
  "Get word at point in original buffer and insert it to minibuffer."
  (interactive)
  (let (word beg)
    (with-current-buffer (window-buffer (minibuffer-selected-window))
      (save-excursion
        (skip-syntax-backward "w_")
        (setq beg (point))
        (skip-syntax-forward "w_")
        (setq word (buffer-substring-no-properties beg (point)))))
    (when word
      (insert word))))

(defun my-minibuffer-setup-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-w") 'my-minibuffer-insert-word-at-point))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'my-minibuffer-setup-hook)
```

**EDIT:**
Note that this is in the standard minibuffer, so you can use it use it anywhere you have a minibuffer prompt, for example in grep, occur, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This is definitely close enough and has the advantage of being more general! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Two answers:

1. [***Replace+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReplacePlus) automatically picks up text at point as the default value when you invoke replace commands.
2. More generally, [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) does something similar to what scottfrazer's code (above) does, but it is more general.  At any time, in any minibuffer, you can hit <kbd>M-.</kbd> (by default) to pick up text ("things") at point and insert it in the minibuffer.  You can repeat this, to either (a) pick up *successive* things (e.g. words) of the *same* kind, accumulating them like <kbd>C-w</kbd> does for Isearch, or (b) pick up alternative, *different* things at point.  More explanation [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Inserting_Text_from_Cursor#RepeatedM.).

Answer (score 2):

I think this exists in Emacs already - you just start replace with `M-S-%` and then press `M-n` (while the minibuffer is empty), this fills in the word under cursor, there are more useful things you can do with this, check http://endlessparentheses.com/predicting-the-future-with-the-m-n-key.html?source=rss#disqus_thread.